# Problemas con la base de datos en joomla 1.5 php 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tube una pagina en 1.5 y ahora quiero recuperar,hice copias de base de datos,estoy instalando el sitio en local con xampp 1.7.4,la cosa que me da fallos la base de datos,me sale esto,he decir que  estoy importando la base,gracias a todos

consulta SQL:

```
--
-- Base de datos: `Sql224515_4`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `jos_agora_censoring`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_agora_censoring` (

`id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`search_for` VARCHAR( 60 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`replace_with` VARCHAR( 60 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> #1046 - No database selected

Tambien tengo problemas con otra base de datos me sale esto

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jos_4rss_feedpost`;
```

> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> #1046 - No database selected

y otra base me dice esto, las 3 son diferentes que no tienen el misno tamaño, a ver si me podeis orientar

```
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `jos_4rss_feedpost`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_4rss_feedpost` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`published` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`feed_url` text NOT NULL,
`created` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`sectionid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`keywords` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`frontpage` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL default 'Not set',
`ordering` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
`link_original` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`duplicate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Feeds and data for feed2post' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> #1046 - No database selected

Comment: La base de datos se llama `Sql224515_4`? Si es así, entonces coloca al principio de todos los sql: `USE Sql224515_4;` Obviamente ya debe estar creada esa BD.

Comment: No me funciona,gracias por tu ayuda